# Issues with logic in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, if-statement, swift3

I'm creating a noughts and crosses game in Swift 3. I want an alert to show when the game is won but there is something wrong with my winning logic that I cannot see.

For some reason, the alert works etc., but the user can click anywhere and it will appear even though I've specifically said where to touch. So the way I've tried to put it is that if three images = each other, user =1 if not then user = 2. and if user = 1 then the win alert is triggered. But it seems at the minute that every time the user touches winner changes to 1 anyway. Can anyone shed some light onto why this is?

alert() is currently only called in the horizontal win function for now to save time etc.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var cross: UIImage!
@IBOutlet var nought: UIImage!
@IBOutlet weak var image1: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image2: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var image3: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    cross = UIImage(named: "Cross.png")
    nought = UIImage(named: "Naught.png")


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
var gamepiece = 1
var whowon = 0

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let user = event?.allTouches!.first!
        if image1.frame.contains((touch?.location(in: self.view))!) {
            if user == 1{
                image1.image = cross
                user = 2

                }
            else{
                image1.image = nought
                user=1
            }
        }
        if image2.frame.contains((touch?.location(in: self.view))!) {
            if user == 1{
                image2.image = cross
                user = 2
            }
            else{
                image2.image = nought
                user=1                    
                }
            }
        if tR.frame.contains((touch?.location(in: self.view))!) {
            if user == 1{
                image3.image = cross
                user = 2                    
        }
        else{
            image3.image = nought
            user=1                    
        }
    }

}

func win(){
    if (image1.image == image2.image || image2.image == image3.image){
        whowon = 1
        alert()
    }
    return true
}
func alert(){
    if (whowon == 1){
        let winner = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Well done.", preferredStyle: .alert)

        let action1 = UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in self.turn.text =  ""
        self.resetBoard()
        }

        let action2 = UIAlertAction(title: "", style: .default) { (alert: UIAlertAction!) -> Void in self.turn.text =  ""
        }

    winner.addAction(action1)
    winner.addAction(action2)        

}
```

Comment: Please limit the code dump to the relevant code to your question.  Have you put a breakpoint in your code to see which of your if/else conditions it is dropping into when you get the unexpected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because when the images views do not have images in them, the `image` property returns `nil`.

Let's say that you placed a cross here:

```
x| |
-|-|-
 | |
-|-|-
 | |
```

Notice how all the image views in the second column has no images? When you compare their `image` property, they are all `nil`! As we all know, `nil` is equal to `nil` so the condition becomes true. To avoid this, just check whether one of the image views doesn't have an image. e.g.

```
(image1.image == image2.image && image2.image == image3.image && image3.image != nil)
```

Comment: @SwiftBeginner Yes that's exactly what you wanted right? Or do you mean that the alert doesn't show even when you are supposed to win?

Comment: The alert doesn't show even when the game has been won.

Comment: @SwiftBeginner where do you call `checkWin()`?

Comment: That was the issue. Working!

Comment: @SwiftBeginner if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark